# Pushing branch to a different repo

Tags: github, push, branch

I made a branch a few days ago and id rather have it put in a different repository. So how can I push a branch into a different repository?

Comment: If you just want to apply the difference to another repository, you can use [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) and [git apply](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply).

Comment: You want to set up a new remote alongside "origin". Then you'd push to that remote. Read up `git remote --help`